# those who(m) he thought were guilty

Tags: relative-clauses, relative-pronouns, whom, who

*The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* (Page 466) says:

> a. *those **whom** he thought were guilty*

> b. *those **who** he thought were guilty*

> Here *who(m)* is subject of the content clause functioning as complement of *thought*: it is not subject of the relative clause itself but of a finite clause embedded within the relative clause. In this construction there is variation between accusative *whom* and nominative *who*.

My understanding of CGEL's explanation above is that *who(m)* is subject of the content clause *who(m) were guilty* and that the relative clause is *he thought*.

If my understanding is correct and if *who(m)* is a relative pronoun here, which I think it is, how could the relative pronoun *who(m)* be subject of the content clause and not part of the relative clause?

Comment: I don't see where the CGEL's explanation says that *who(m)* is not a part of the relative clause. What it's saying is that the content clause *who were guilty* is the relevant clause for determining whether to use *who* or *whom*. [Actually, it seems to say that they're both valid.]

Comment: @PeterShor So the relative clause would be not _he thought_ but _who(m) he thought were guilty_?

Comment: That's the only complete clause around. *whom he thought* doesn't stand alone.

Comment: [*It's common for **those who** are learning English to get confused as to when to use **who** and **whom**.*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22those+whom%22+or+%22those+who%22&oq=%22those+whom%22+or+%22those+who%22&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l7.7877j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) But you won't go far wrong if you stick to ***who*** throughout. (Except *maybe* you might slip ***whom*** in after ***to*** sometimes, just to prove you know that form exists! :)

Comment: @PeterShor Then, how could, _who(m)_, the subject of the subordinate clause, introduce the relative clause?

Comment: @JK2: do you say *he thought them were guilty* or *he thought they were guilty*? The second has the pronoun in the nominative, so it corresponds to *those who he thought were guilty.*

Comment: You might want to consider *Those he thought guilty*.

Comment: The relative clause is "who he thought were guilty". Embedded within the relative clause is the content clause "who were guilty" functioning as complement of "thought", in which "who" is subject.

Comment: @PeterShor I say _they_ in your examples, and _who_ in CGEL's. My question is not about the selection itself but about the identity of _who(m)_.

Comment: @BillJ I now can see how the RC is _who(m) he thought were guilty_. What I still can't wrap my head around is how the "embedded" content clause _who(m) were guilty_ is not placed within the RC and how _he thought_ is placed within the "embedded" content clause.

Comment: @JK2 The embedded content clause **is** within the RC. It functions as complement of "thought", so we have "... those [whom he thought [___ were guilty]], where gap is co-referenced to "who(m)". The outer brackets surround the RC, while the inner brackets surround the embedded content clause.

Comment: @BillJ That makes sense. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The second case is the simplest to analyse

> b. those who he thought were guilty

Step 1 - those who (he thought) were guilty

Step 2 - those who were guilty (he thought)

Step 3 - those who were guilty, he thought  (nominative)

---

> a. those whom he thought were guilty

This supposes that "to think" is being used transitively. It seems doubtful in this case.

I can say "I think many thoughts" but what is the direct object in sentence (a)? Is it "whom", I don't believe so.

Some years back, it was idiomatic to say, "He thought John guilty", "He thought Mary shallow", "He thought them impertinent."

These were contractions of: "He thought John to be guilty", "He thought Mary to be shallow", "He thought them to be impertinent."

So think has traditionally been used in transitive form and so we could, according to this convention say:

those **whom** he thought **to be** guilty

The reason this is acceptable is that the infinitive cannot take a subject.

Comment: It's not impossible for an infinitive to take a subject. After all, that one just did. :)

Comment: @tchrist I'm not sure if I could say that _whom_ in the last example is subject of the infinitival _to be guilty_. The subject of the infinitival is missing and the missing subject is understood as  _whom_, but does this make _whom_ subject of the infinitival? In _I want them to be dead_, for example, is it correct to say _them_ is subject of _to be dead_ simply because the subject of the infinitival is missing and the missing subject is understood as _them_? If it's correct, should _them to be dead_ be treated as a non-finite clause?

Comment: @JK2 I could say it without any difficulty. If you don't allow transformations like Relative Clause Formation, you're gonna have way more construction types to account for than there are categories. It's hard enough with derivations.

Comment: @JohnLawler I take it that you could say that _whom_ in the last example is subject of the infinitival _to be guilty_. But the rest of your comment is just beyond me. :)

Answer (score 1):

> *those who he thought were guilty*

is a noun phrase consisting of a head noun -- in this case a demonstrative pronoun *those*, meaning *those people* by presupposition -- followed and modified by a restrictive ("integrated", in CGEL's terminology) relative clause *who he thought were guilty.*

The relative clause always contains its relative pronoun, but the relative pronoun is not always a constituent of the matrix relative clause. Normally it's the subject

- *those **who** came to scoff*

or the object

- *those **whom** we scoffed at*

or even the object of a pied-piped preposition

- *those **at whom** we scoffed*.

But not in this case. The relative clause here has **two** verbs:

1. *thought*, past tense third person singular, subject *he*;

and

2. *were*, past tense third person plural, subject *who* (identifying the antecedent *those*).

This means two tensed clauses, each with its own verb, but different subjects, one singular and one plural.

The relative pronoun *who* is extracted and moved (to the beginning of the relative clause, right after *those*) from the complement clause, where it is a subject. By the strict nominative rule for all subject pronouns, **whom* should be excluded in this case. Yet CGEL says there is variation.

This is another way of saying that different people follow different rules where *whom* is concerned. [As Pullum has pointed out graphically](http://itre.cis.upenn.edu/%7Emyl/languagelog/archives/001437.html), for many English speakers the dead pronoun *whom* has ascended to the high-faluting pantheon of words that one throws into a sentence to make it more "formal". Or something.

Comment: Funny how nobody ever says that they thought that ✼him was guilty, but the moment you move the subject around they get all confused about this.

Comment: @tchrist But nobody would ever say _those whom was thought to be guilty_. So the choice of _who(m)_ seems to be affected by the closest clause, albeit illogical.

Comment: Not illogical at all. Speech is linear and what comes next is most important in interpreting what's just been heard. The more intervening material one puts between one part of a constituent and another, the more likely will be mistaken interpretations of what one says. English has a lot of syntax that shifts things around, but it's pretty flexible in that it's so novel. English syntax as we know it today has been invented over a very short historical period -- something like 5-600 years. And everybody makes up their own grammar, which is always different from others in unpredictable ways.

Answer (score 1):

> 1) He thought [that] they were guilty.

Here, we have a matrix clause and a content clause.   The verb of the matrix clause is "thought".   Its subject is "he" and its direct object is the content clause.   The verb of the content clause is "were".   It's subject is "they" and it's subject complement is "guilty".   An optional "that" functions as a subordinator.

> 2) those who(m) he thought were guilty.

Here, we have a relative clause modifying "those".   The words that remain the same between these two examples also retain their functions.   The notable difference is that "who(m)" takes on the functions of both "that" and "they".   Additionally, it *relates* the matrix clause which contains it to the pronoun "those".

> Here who(m) is subject of the content clause functioning as complement of thought:

Where I said "direct object", this says "complement".   Disregarding that, "who(m)" is the subject of "were", and "who(m) ... were guilty" is the argument of the verb "thought".   That is to say, "who(m)" serves the same job in 2) that "they" serves in 1).

> it is not subject of the relative clause itself but of a finite clause **embedded within** the relative clause.

What we're regarding as the relative clause is a matrix clause.   It's the clause with the verb "thought".   The subject of "thought" is "he", not "who(m)".   "Who(m)" is a subject, but it's the subject of "were".   In other words, "who(m)" is not the subject of the relative clause, but rather the subordinate content clause.   That is, of course, an embedded finite clause.

> In this construction there is variation between accusative whom and nominative who.

Some people use "who", some people use "whom".  That's variation.  'Nuff said.

There is something that **isn't** said.   Not one part of that CGEL passage claims that the relative pronoun is not a part of the relative clause.   What is says is that it does not act **on its own** as a constituent of that clause.

Here's where you've gone astray:  the relative clause is **not** simply "he thought".   The clause "he thought" does not exist in this example at all.   Those two words are the two words **of** the relative clause that are not **also** parts of the content clause.

The content clause is "who(m) ... were guilty". 
The relative clause is "who(m) he thought were guilty".

The content clause is **embedded within** the relative clause.

The "who(m)" attaches the entire relative clause to the pronoun "those".   It can't do that if it's buried behind the subject and verb of its matrix clause.   If we bother to use it at all, we bring that word (or, as in the case of pied-piping, the smallest constituent containing it) to the front of the clause, which conveniently places it next to the word to which it relates.

As it is not the subject of the relative clause, it also happens to be optional:

> those he thought were guilty

Expressing the relative clause as a contact clause, however, simply isn't relevant to the **choice** between "who" and "whom".   Rather, it's relevant to avoiding the choice entirely.